# Find $\dim \operatorname{Ker}T$

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification, linear-transformations

Let $T : \mathbb{R}_4[x] → \mathbb{R}$ be the linear transformation defined by $T(p(x)) = p(1)$. Find $\dim \operatorname{Ker}T$.

So $\operatorname{Ker}T=\left \{ a+bx+cx^2+dx^3 : a+b+c+d=0 \right \}$

$= (a+bx+cx^2+dx^3) \in\operatorname{Ker}T$ iff $((-b-c-d)+bx+cx^2+dx^3) \in \operatorname{Ker}T$

$= b(-1+x)+c(-1+x^2)+d(-1+x^3) = \operatorname{span}\left \{-1+x , -1+x^2,-1+x^3 \right \}$

And clearly $\left \{-1+x , -1+x^2,-1+x^3 \right \}$ is LI so its a basis for $\operatorname{Ker}T$, so $\dim\operatorname{Ker}T = 3$.

Is that correct?

Is there a better way to solve this?

Thanks!

Comment: Looks good to me.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Your solution is correct. Here is an alternative: for any linear transformation, the dimension of the domain ist equal to the Dimension of the Image plus the Dimension of the Kernel. your Domain ist Dimension 4, and it should be easy to see that your map is surjective. So the Image is one dimensional, leaving three dimensional for the kernel.

Google "Rank nullity Theorem" for details. Or "isomorphism Theorem" for a more general version.

Comment: Cool, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I knew it was $3$ right away, because you have four unknowns, $a,b,c,d$ and one "constraint", $a+b+c+d=0$.  This sort of trick can be effective.

Comment: Can you explain more please? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

as you concluded,vctor of **kerT** coordinate (a,b,c,d),only need to find dim(**kerT**),isomorphism to coordinate,dim=dim(solution space),a+b+c+d=0.
dim=n-rank(1,1,1,1)=4-1=3

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 0):

or as simon mentioned .
**α** is base of **R**4(x)1,T(**α**)=**α**A,
matrix A is[image]
R(A)=1
dimKer=n-R(A)
thanks simon ,I am learning about range and kernel.